# selecting fields from multiple MySQL tables and what does (1=2) mean?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm trying to understand what is happening in the following Coldfusion/MySQL query I'm having to update (and I'm in my first month of CF/MySQL).

I have a query running before a search, which sets the variable **pl** (pricelists) like so:

```
<cfif variables.module IS "yes"> 
  <cfquery datasource="ds" name="qp">
      <!--- selects pricelist and seller --->
  </cfquery>
  <cfset variables.pl = "LEFT JOIN pricelist p ON ">
  <cfoutput query="qp" >
    <cfif qp.preislist IS ''>
        <cfset variables.pl= variables.pl & '(p.iln = a.iln AND p.preislist = "AAA" AND p.ean = a.ean AND p.iln = "#qp.seller#") OR '>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset variables.pl= variables.pl & '(p.iln = a.iln AND p.preisliste = "#qp.preislist#" AND p.ean = a.ean AND p.iln = "#qp.seller#") OR '>
    </cfif>
  </cfoutput>
  <cfset variables.pl = variables.preislisten & "(1=0)">
</cfif>
```

This then is "ported" to the search query adding to my confusion like so:

```
<cfquery datasource="ds" name="getArt">
    SELECT a.* <cfif variables.module IS "yes">, p.ek, p.vk, p.waehrung, p.onlinepreis</cfif>
    FROM artdata a
    <cfif variables.module IS "yes">
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cfsql_varchar" value="#variables.pl#"> 
    </cfif>
    ....
```

**Plenty of questions:**
 - there is no need to cfparam query fields such as *qp.seller*, or is there?
 - shouldn't I always use ALIAS as in *artdata AS a* vs only using *artdata a*?
 - Can I select *p.ek, p.vk, ...* like this although the pricelist table will only be declared later on through the variable *variables.pl* (being *LEFT JOIN pricelist p ON*...)
 - What's up with the (1=0)? What is the purpose of it is? Dito for (3=2), (1=2).

Thanks for some enlightenment!

Comment: All I can tell is that `1=0` is a very common way of saying `false` (ensuring boolean scalar context) in standard, dialect-agnostic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there is no need to cfparam query fields such as qp.seller, or is there?

It's not cfparam it's cfqueryparam - these are two different tags that perform different tasks.

There are two key reasons for using cfqueryparam:

1) for security - if the input might have originally come from any third-party, or if you cannot guarantee that the input is a known value, use cfqueryparam to ensure no SQL code injection (intentional or accidental) takes place.

2) for performance - query parameters result in an execution plan which can be cached and applied to multiple queries (i.e. where the parameters vary), and thus often lead to improved performance.

If qp.seller is a numeric foreign key that's guaranteed safe, you don't need it for security but it still may have beneficial effects from a performance aspect.

In general, **if in doubt, use it**.

<sub>(There are occasional instances of people claiming it results in bad execution plans which cause worse performance, but I'm wary of those claims and in any case that would have to be dealt with on a case-by-case basis - security is important.)</sub>

> shouldn't I always use ALIAS as in artdata AS a vs only using artdata a?

If you like typing more. :)

There's no difference/benefit to the AS keyword for table names.

> Can I select p.ek, p.vk, ... like this

Yep, that'll work.

Might like to put them on multiple lines though to make it more readable.

> although the pricelist table will only be declared later on through the variable > variables.pl (being LEFT JOIN pricelist p ON...)

This is an incorrect assumption.

Using cfqueryparam specifically prevents SQL code from being injected, which is what you are trying to do with it here.

Instead of creating variables.pl, you should be outputting this generated SQL directly into the cfquery tag where it will be used.

*(If you're not sure what I mean I can do an example for this?)*

> What's up with the (1=0)? What is the purpose of it is? Dito for (3=2), (1=2).

As explained by Romain's comment, it's a common way of saying false, used when you have dynamic queries. The parentheses are optional.

It is however more common  to put it at the *start* - i.e. `WHERE 1=0` or `JOIN 1=0` - and then have the dynamic statements starting `OR ...` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

**- there is no need to cfparam query fields such as qp.seller, or is there?**

First off, this is `cfqueryparam`, not `cfparam`. `cfqueryparam` is for data sanitization. `cfparam` is for ensuring that a variable exists with some sort of value. Is there a need to use it? IF you are explicitly creating/setting variables.pl, then no. But it's still a good practice. cfqueryparam-ing the data ensures data integrity if you or someone else changes the setting code later on. It also helps you know at a glance what sort of data the variable holds.

**- shouldn't I always use ALIAS as in artdata AS a vs only using artdata a?**

As I understand it, you should. All the databases I've used have supported the `tablename alias` syntax, but I *believe* the ANSI standard is to use the `AS`, which would make your code more portable.

**- Can I select p.ek, p.vk, ... like this although the pricelist table will only be declared later on through the variable variables.pl (being LEFT JOIN pricelist p ON...)**

Yes. This is fairly common (at least where I work).

**- What's up with the (1=0)? What is the purpose of it is? Dito for (3=2), (1=2).**

This was answered well in the comments by Romain. It's a forced true/false value. It is often used when generating SQL statements on the fly to ensure that there is at least one `WHERE` clause generated.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "there is no need to cfparam query fields such as qp.seller, or is there?": One thing that I haven't seen mentioned yet is the fact that cfqueryparam is only valid within the context of a cfquery tag.  Since you are constructing a SQL block outside of a cfquery tag context, you won't be able to use cfqueryparam there for qp.seller.  Therefore, you have some choices -

1. Move your SQL code into your cfquery block and use cfqueryparam.
2. Create a stored procedure or function in your database that takes qp.seller as an argument.
3. Use some kind of data-validating regular expression to verify that #qp.seller# is a valid value.
4. Do nothing, and trust that since you have control over the source of the data being used as an input to your query, you don't have to worry about SQL Injection (you'll still lose out on a possible performance improvement, however).

The other posters have answered your other questions well enough - I have nothing more to add on those.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good practice if the type for qp.seller is something other than a string (number, date, etc...).  This is similar to my option #3.  The reason I didn't say that specifically for #3 is that it appears your value is a string, in which case validating that it is a string doesn't go very far, in terms of validation.  You would probably need a regex to look deeper into the string to make sure it doesn't have invalid characters or that it meets a particular pattern.

Comment: You could use the `pattern` option for cfparam, I guess, and that would do the regex checking I mentioned.